# Delphi 7 - PNG Image isn't showing

Tags: image, delphi, png, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 Pro. I have installed the PNG Component in my project, but whenever I load a PNG image into the `Image1` component, the application starts but its main form is invisible. If I load a JPEG or a bitmap file, the form is shown. Here's the code I'm using in my form constructor:

```
procedure TFMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  regn, tmpRegn, x, y: integer;
  nullClr: TColor;
  Settings: TInifile;
begin
  FMain.Brush.Bitmap := Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
  nullClr := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0];
  regn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Image1.Picture.Graphic.Width, Image1.Picture.Graphic.Height);
  for x := 1 to Image1.Picture.Graphic.Width do
    for y := 1 to Image1.Picture.Graphic.Height do
      if Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x - 1, y - 1] = nullClr then
      begin
        tmpRegn := CreateRectRgn(x - 1, y - 1, x, y);
        CombineRgn(regn, regn, tmpRegn, RGN_DIFF);
        DeleteObject(tmpRegn);
      end;
  SetWindowRgn(FMain.Handle, regn, True);
end;
```

Why is this happening ? What should I change so I can use PNG image in my `Image1` ?

The whole code:

```
unit UnitMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Gauges, Buttons, IniFiles, StdCtrls, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ExtCtrls,
  Wininet, ImgBtn, ComCtrls, ShlObj, ComObj, ActiveX, jpeg;


type
  TFMain = class(TForm)
    Gauge1: TGauge;
    Gauge2: TGauge;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    ImgBtn1: TImgBtn;
    ImgBtn2: TImgBtn;
    ImgBtn3: TImgBtn;
    ImgBtn4: TImgBtn;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Image2: TImage;
    Image3: TImage;
    Image4: TImage;
    Label4: TLabel;
    ImgBtn5: TImgBtn;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ImgBtn4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure ImgBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure UpdateRevision(Rev: string);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    Draging: Boolean;
    X0, Y0: integer;
  end;

var
  FMain: TFMain;
  USettings : TStrings;

implementation

uses
  Frm2, GetFilesThr, Misc;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFmain.UpdateRevision(Rev: string);
var
  Settings: TInifile;
begin
  Settings := TInifile.Create(USettings[0] + '_settings.ini');
  Settings.WriteString('main', 'AtRevision', Rev);
  Settings.Free;
end;


function LoadSettings(): bool;
var
  Settings: TInifile;
begin
  Result := False;
  USettings := TStringlist.Create;
  USettings.Add(GetCurrentDir + '\');

  if(FileExists(USettings[0] + '_settings.ini')) then
  begin
    Settings := TInifile.Create(USettings[0] + '_settings.ini');
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'NewsUrl', ''));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'UpdatesUrl', ''));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'LinkName', 'Lineage II'));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'Installed', '0'));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'CreateBackup', '0'));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'AtRevision', '0'));
    USettings.Add(Settings.ReadString('main', 'RunCustom', 'system\l2.exe'));
    Settings.Free;
    Result := True;
  end
end;

// ρξηδΰες πλϋκ νΰ ρεα νΰ πΰαξχεμ ρςξλε
procedure CreateDesktopIcon(ilname, WorkDir, desc : string);
var
  IObj: IUnknown;
  SLink: IShellLink;
  PFile: IPersistFile;
  desk: string;
  lnkpath: WideString;
begin
  if(ilname <> '') then
  begin
    SetLength(desk, MAX_PATH + 1);
    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, PAnsiChar(desk), CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, False);
    lnkpath:= PChar(desk) + '\' + ilname + '.lnk';
    IObj := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
    SLink := IObj as IShellLink;
    PFile := IObj as IPersistFile;

    with SLink do
    begin
      SetDescription(PChar(desc));
      SetPath(PChar(Application.ExeName));
      SetWorkingDirectory(PAnsiChar(WorkDir));
    end;

    PFile.Save(PWChar(WideString(lnkpath)), FALSE);
  end;
end;

procedure TFMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  regn, tmpRegn, x, y: integer;
  nullClr: TColor;
  s_load: bool;
  Settings: TInifile;
begin
  s_load := LoadSettings();
  if (s_load) then
  begin
    if (USettings[4] = '0') then
    begin
      Settings := TInifile.Create(USettings[0] + '_settings.ini');
      Settings.WriteString('main','Installed', '1');
      Settings.Free;
      CreateDesktopIcon(USettings[3], USettings[0], 'Play Lineage II');
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    FMain.Timer1.Enabled := False;
    ShowMessage('ERROR: _settings.ini Not Found !');
    Application.Terminate; // .close ηδερό νε οπξιδες 
  end;

  // Νΰβξδθμ κπΰρθβξρςό νΰ τξπμσ ...
  FMain.brush.bitmap := Image1.picture.bitmap;
  nullClr := image1.picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0];
  regn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, image1.picture.Graphic.Width, image1.picture.Graphic.Height);

  for x := 1 to image1.picture.Graphic.Width do
    for y := 1 to image1.picture.Graphic.Height do
      if image1.picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x - 1, y - 1] = nullClr then
      begin
        tmpRegn := CreateRectRgn(x - 1, y - 1, x, y);
        CombineRgn(regn, regn, tmpRegn, RGN_DIFF);
        DeleteObject(tmpRegn);
      end;
  SetWindowRgn(FMain.handle, regn, true);
end;

procedure TFMain.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Draging := true;
  x0 := x;
  y0 := y;
end;

procedure TFMain.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Draging := false;
end;

procedure TFMain.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Draging then
  begin
    FMain.Left := FMain.Left + X - X0;
    FMain.top := FMain.top + Y - Y0;
  end;
end;

procedure TFMain.ImgBtn4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMain.Close;
end;

procedure TFMain.ImgBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMain.Close;
end;

procedure TFMain.ImgBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WThread: GFilesThread;
begin
  Label3.Caption := '';
  WThread := GFilesThread.Create(True);
  WThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  WThread.UpdatesUrl := USettings[2];
  WThread.ForceCheck := True;
  WThread.CreateBackup := StrToInt(USettings[5]);
  WThread.LocalRevision := StrToInt(USettings[6]);
  WThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TFMain.ImgBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RunApp(USettings[0] + Usettings[7]);
  FMain.Close;
end;

procedure TFMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 USettings.Free;
end;

procedure TFMain.ImgBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 FMain.Enabled := False;
 Form1.Show;
end;

procedure TFMain.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
 FMain.Panel1.Visible := True;
 FMain.Image2.Visible := True;
 FMain.Image3.Visible := True;
 FMain.Image4.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TFMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  WThread: GFilesThread;
begin
  FMain.Timer1.Enabled := False;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(USettings[1]);
  Label3.Caption := '';
  WThread := GFilesThread.Create(True);
  WThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  WThread.UpdatesUrl := USettings[2];
  WThread.ForceCheck := False;
  WThread.CreateBackup := StrToInt(USettings[5]);
  WThread.LocalRevision := StrToInt(USettings[6]);
  WThread.Resume;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include your code here. Having it somewhere else means it can't be searched, and it's not available if the external site is unavailable for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: added the whole code. I thinks there's a problem with the ''first code'' i posted. I think it makes all *.png images invisible or something like that. In my opinion whatever color exists in the pixel with position (0,0) of the image becomes transparent. and that messes with the png images.

Comment: @TLama i didnt work, now i cant even compile it. Isnt there a solution to just remove the procedure that make any bitmap image i insert into the form invisible?

Comment: You must not access `Image1.Picture.Bitmap`. It releases the image data. Besides, are you aware of [`layered windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#layered) ? I believe it would simplify your task.